# IntelliJ / Android Studio - how to activate proguard to obfuscate code - step by step?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, proguard

I was searching everywhere for answer, but did not find any.

The main problem is that eveyone says about proguard configuration file, but there is none, IntelliJ / Android Studio does not generate such a file, there is none in SDK dir, so how do I generate valid configuration file for proguard obfuscation?

Answer (score 7):

I know i'm bit late in answering but here is the answer
This blog contains all the stuff you need from the scratch step by step with images.

1. In android Studio open your project in Project view
2. Open app's build.gradle file.
3. Change

minifyEnable false

to

minifyEnable true

These are steps to enable the proguard. If you want advance view then you can visit following link.

[Blogger have answered very briefly on this topic](http://dominoc925.blogspot.in/2015/01/enabling-proguard-obfuscation-in.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Flash Thunder if this help you then accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have android-sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt and proguard-android-optimize.txt. Make sure you have "Android SDK Tools" installed with SDK Manager. I think IntelliJ usually generates proguard-project.txt in the project directory. If not, it's just a text file, so you can just add it to your project. You set your custom rules in that file.

You can even check the "Run ProGuard when building debug APK" in Project Structure window (F4):

[image]

Comment: In my case the file name was `proguard-rules.pro`, can't find the option you are mentioning about.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea. I assumed you mean either-or. But yeah, Android Studio is probably a bit different.

Comment: I'm sorry, was my bad. I thought it was the same in latest version, but it's not.

Comment: No problem dude. Maybe it helps someone else using IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

In Andoird Studio we cant see the `proguard-rules.pro` file in the **Project** tab by default. to change this you can do the following:

- Change the view to **Project** instead of **Android**:

[image: change view]

- Now that you have done it you can view the `proguard-rules.pro` file inside **yourproject/app/proguard-rules.pro**. (see screenshot)

[image: See screenshot]

The rest of the proguard configuration is traditional and you can find plenty of info by googling it. `:)` Hope it helps.